# php preg_replace html tags issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this html code.

```
 <P class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'><STRONG>text</P>
    <P class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'></P>
    <UL>
    <LI>
    <DIV class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV class=MsoNormal style='MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 10pt'>text</DIV></LI></UL>
```

I want remove style tag and its proprieties as well as class tag and its proprieties so the out would be :

```
  <P><STRONG>text</P>
    <P></P>
    <UL>
    <LI>
    <DIV>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV>text</DIV></LI>
    <LI>
    <DIV>text</DIV></LI></UL>
```

Here is what i have tried but it is not working :

```
$html = preg_replace('/(]+) (style|class)=("|\').*?("|\'(>|\s))/img', '$1', $$html);
```

Comment: a) In what way is it not working? b) You can't parse HTML with regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127

Comment: this is the error that it gives : PHP Error[8]: Undefined variable: return the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$html = preg_replace("/(\s(class|style)[^>]+)/", "", $html);
```

Comment: just tried it it gives the same error PHP Error[8]: Undefined variable:

Comment: thanks zekus works after changing $$html to $html. how can i remove if it exists the <img> tag too ??